# How do you detect if a user has a keyboard via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a site where I'm globally binding certain keys to shortcuts using the `keyup` event. For example, if someone presses the A key, a menu opens.

I don't want to bind these triggers on mobile devices (such as phones and tablets). However, there's a number of people that use keyboards with their tablets. How would I detect if a keyboard input exists via Javascript? I know I can detect touch devices based on if `touchstart` exists, but that wouldn't work for people who are on tablets and have keyboards plugged in. I only want to bind the `keyup` events if a keyboard is present. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Note: I know this is a nice-to-have, but I'd like to do it if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you bind to `keyup` in all cases... if the user doesn't have a keyboard, it will not do anything.

Comment: I just didn't want to bind unnecessary events. Does it matter much or is it no big deal?

Comment: If it is just one keyup handler, it is absolutely no big deal. The code you would write to NOT include the handler would probably be a bigger deal.

Comment: I think, phone browsers generally emulate keyboard events for compatibility with existing scripts. At least those on Android devices that I had worked with do so (not perfectly, though). So presence of keyboard events is not an indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You could always attach a catch-all event handler to the document object that lazily attaches your event handlers after the user hits any key.